# ionic V1 build gradle error when build app to android

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, build.gradle

I have an android app that was developped in IonicV1 (3.19.1). When I try to build the project (ionic cordova build android) I get this build errors:

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.049 secs
Could not find tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:25.2.3).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/25.2.3/tracker-25.2.3.jar

> Could not find lint-checks.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/25.2.3/lint-checks-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.2.3/baseLibrary-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/25.2.3/layoutlib-api-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/25.2.3/dvlib-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/repository/25.2.3/repository-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find lint-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/25.2.3/lint-api-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/25.2.3/annotations-25.2.3.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  (node:5488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.2.3/builder-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find lint.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.2.3/lint-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.2.3/gradle-api-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find compilerCommon.jar (com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.2.3/compilerCommon-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/2.2.3/builder-model-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find builder-test-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/2.2.3/builder-test-api-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/25.2.3/sdklib-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/25.2.3/sdk-common-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/25.2.3/manifest-merger-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/25.2.3/ddmlib-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/25.2.3/protos-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find shared.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/25.2.3/shared-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find tracker.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/25.2.3/tracker-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find lint-checks.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/25.2.3/lint-checks-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.2.3/baseLibrary-2.2.3.jar
> Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/25.2.3/layoutlib-api-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/25.2.3/dvlib-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/repository/25.2.3/repository-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find lint-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/25.2.3/lint-api-25.2.3.jar
> Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:25.2.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/25.2.3/annotations-25.2.3.jar

This started hapening after I updated Android Studio to the last version. I can't update my Ionic version to the new version, because of the app.

node -v: 8.9.4
cordova -v: 8.0.0
ionic-v: 3.19.1
npm-v: 5.6.0
java JDK -v: 1.8.0
gradle -v: 6.9.1 and 7.1 (tried both)

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

// Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
// installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
// http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
// and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

I really don't know what to do to solve this problem. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

today (23-june-2023) Jcenter stop there services,

February 3, 2021 jFrog announced that they will be shutting down Jcenter

remove Jcenter() from build.gradle and check with mavenCentral, jitpack

also you can check this link https://developer.android.com/build/jcenter-migration

jcneter status: https://status.gradle.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).